# Add Fragment tabs as child tab of Action Bar Tab in Android

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar, android-appcompat, fragment-tab-host

Hello I want to add sub tabs of `Action Bar` Tabs in Android. I have two parents `Action Bar` Tabs. I want something like when click on parent `ActionBar` Tab 1 then it should show two sub tabs of that parent tab 1 and on click on parent `Action Bar` Tab 2 then it should show three sub tabs of that parent tab 2.

I see this can be done using `FragmentTabHost` but anyone how to add FragmentTabHost dynamically on click on ActionBar Tabs ?

Here which I am trying to add two parents tab which added successfully but I did not find how to add sub tabs.

```
private ActionBar mActionBar;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mActionBar = getSupportActionBar();

    ActionBar.Tab firstTab = mActionBar.newTab().setText("First Tab").setTabListener(this);
    mActionBar.addTab(firstTab);

    ActionBar.Tab secondTab = mActionBar.newTab().setText("Second Tab").setTabListener(this);
    mActionBar.addTab(secondTab);

    mActionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
}
```

[image]